# Generate a percent of all possible combinations from a list of numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations

I know that `itertools.combinations(iterable, r)` returns combinations of a list/tuple of elements (as an iterable). How can I build a function around it that returns only x% of all combinations? (i just need a list of tuples, so it does not have to be an iterator). I want that if there are very few combinations, for example nCn, it should return all (in this case one) of them (so minimum 1).

Comment: does it have to be a percentage or do you need all combinations up to a fixed number? If you need up to a maximum number of combinations you could just do this via indexing...

Comment: You can use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to set a maximum amount of combinations to retrieve, e.g. `itertools.islice(itertools.combinations(iterable, r), MAX_COMBS)` (if it has less than `MAX_COMBS` it will still work). You can also make `MAX_COMBS` dependant on the number of combinations, e.g. `max(round(0.2 * math.comb(len(iterable), r)), MIN_COMBS)`.

Comment: it would be useful if it could be a percentage

Comment: @jdehesa that looks nice, mind turning it into a more detailed answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: Do you know how many elements the iterable could return?

Comment: @Kalpit well, you simply compute rCn ? I don't understand the question? I just want to obtain a percent of rCn, as tuples in a list, where the elements in the tuples are the elements in the original iterable.

Comment: you can use `random.sample` to take a certain amount from `combinations`

Comment: @Tomerikoo does that work directly on combinations? Mind writing this as an answer with a small example?

Comment: Do you actually need it randomized? Or that doesn't matter? If you just want the `x%` first combinations just use slicing...

Comment: @Tomerikoo randomization is important, as I use it to sample multiple times, and I cannot reuse the same combinations over and over

Comment: Only problem with that is to make it random you will have to convert the iterator (`combinations`) into an actual list. If you're working with big iterables or large `r` values, this might be very expensive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) you can produce an iterator with an upper bound in the number of elements:

```py
import itertools

MAX_COMBS = 2
combs = itertools.combinations(range(3), 2)
combs_slice = itertools.islice(combs, MAX_COMBS)
print(*combs_slice, sep='\n')
# (0, 1)
# (0, 2)
```

If the size of the iterable has a `len`, then you can make the upper limit dependant on the total number of combinations:

```py
import itertools
import math

# Percentage of combinations to draw
COMB_RATIO = 0.2
# Lower bound for number of combinations
MIN_COMBS = 2

iterable = range(5)
k = 3
combs = itertools.combinations(iterable, k)
max_combs = max(round(COMB_RATIO * math.comb(len(iterable), k)), MIN_COMBS)
combs_slice = itertools.islice(combs, max_combs)
print(*combs_slice, sep='\n')
# (0, 1, 2)
# (0, 1, 3)
# (0, 1, 4)

iterable = range(3)
k = 2
combs = itertools.combinations(iterable, k)
max_combs = max(round(COMB_RATIO * math.comb(len(iterable), k)), MIN_COMBS)
combs_slice = itertools.islice(combs, max_combs)
print(*combs_slice, sep='\n')
# (0, 1)
# (0, 2)
```

Note: [`math.comb`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.comb) was introduced in Python 3.8, if you are in a previous version you may need to roll your own implementation, or take it e.g. [from SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.comb.html).

Comment: Is there also a way to return a random set of k combinations, instead of the first k ones?

Comment: @Qubix That would be a different thing... You could do something like `sample_idx = sorted(random.sample(range(math.comb(n, k)), num_combs_to_sample))`, then iterate the combinations with `enumerate` until you find all indices... However, if the number of sampled combinations is much smaller than the total number of combinations, you may be better off generating them from the indices, as in the function `nth_combination` from [Itertools Recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

Comment: thanks for the answer. I tried the code above, python 3.8, I am getting : AttributeError: module 'math' has no attribute 'comb' . Any idea why?

Comment: @Qubix Not really, if it's a release 3.8 version (not alpha or something like that) it should have [`math.comb`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.comb). Check [`sys.version`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.version) to make sure it's the right one.

Comment: actually it's a google colab notebook. The notebook kernel says Python 3.8, the sys.version says : '3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) \n[GCC 8.3.0]'

Comment: Ok, running now. In the first part of the code, MIN_COMBS seems to have no effect. Even if I put comb_ratio to 0, I still get the same number of combs. Comb_Ratio is also never used.

Comment: @Qubix Ugh, sorry, pasted the wrong thing in the second snippet, added `COMB_RATIO`. `MIN_COMBS` is supposed to be the minimum number of combinations that you will get, even if the percentage of the total number of combinations is less than that - so setting it to zero does not do anything... (you may still get less than `MIN_COMBS` if the total number of combinations is smaller).

Answer (score 0):

Because iterators don't carry the information of how long their collections are, you cannot obtain the length from it.

In your case, you could determine the size of the combination using the formula n!/(k! (n-k)!) and iterate until your percentage.

For instance:

```py
from math import factorial, ceil

def my_combinations():
    ratio = .2 # 20 percent
    a = range(10)
    n = len(a)
    k = 5
    it = itertools.combinations(a, k)
    total_combinations = factorial(n) / factorial(k) / factorial(n-k)

    for _ in range(ceil(total_combinations * ratio)):
        yield it.next()
```

Comment: Hi, one small thing, can I introduce a shuffle there somewhere, so that if I call the function on the same list twice, I get slightly different results?

Comment: That's a fair point. I don't think that will be possible via the method I proposed.